# How do I combine several ggplot2 plots using patchwork?

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

When trying to add two ggplot objects (plots) using `+` from `patchwork`, I get the error as shown below. What could be the issue?

```
require(patchwork)
ex.df <- data.table(
  x1 = rnorm(1000, 20, 50),
  x2 = rnorm(1000, 4, 5)
)

plt1 <- ex.df |> 
  ggplot() +
  geom_density(aes(x = x1))

plt2 <- ex.df |> 
  ggplot() +
  geom_density(aes(x = x2))
plt1 + plt2
```

[image]

This happens even when I use the `wrap_plots` function

Comment: What does your `sessionInfo()` look like? I was using R 4.3.3 on Windows 11 x64 with `ggplot2_3.5.0` and `patchwork_1.2.0` and can't re-create your error: the plots render perfectly well.

Comment: There have been a few questions about this recently e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78171344/patchwork-doesnt-render-in-quarto). Seems to be a version mismatch between `ggplot2 3.5.0` and `patchwork`. If you update `patchwork` the problem should resolve itself.

Answer (score 1):

With `data.frame`:

(Also works for me with data.table per second plot.)

```r
library(ggplot2)
require(patchwork)

ex.df <- data.frame(
  x1 = rnorm(1000, 20, 50),
  x2 = rnorm(1000, 4, 5)
)

plt1 <- ex.df |> 
  ggplot() +
  geom_density(aes(x = x1))

plt2 <- ex.df |> 
  ggplot() +
  geom_density(aes(x = x2))

plt1 + plt2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-17 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
require(patchwork)

ex.df <- data.table(
  x1 = rnorm(1000, 20, 50),
  x2 = rnorm(1000, 4, 5)
)

plt1 <- ex.df |> 
  ggplot() +
  geom_density(aes(x = x1))

plt2 <- ex.df |> 
  ggplot() +
  geom_density(aes(x = x2))

plt1 + plt2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-17 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>